# Overlay TIFF with raster layer

Tags: qgis, merge, overlay

I am using QGIS 3.23.3-Lima.

- Input files TIFF: 12 TIFF files with species abundance data (output
  of a species distribution model)
- Input file shape: Esri shapefile with the 12 biogeorgions.

Aim: One TIFF file considering biogeoregion 1 form TIFF 1 and biogeoregion 2 from TIFF 2 etc.

My solution:

1. All 12 TIFF files: Vector creation, raster pixels to points.
2. All 12 point files: Vector overlay, intersection
3. Attribute table of all 12 point files: delete the unnecessary biogeregions.
4. GDAL, Raster miscellaneous, merge the 12 point files to one TIFF file.

Does anyone know of a simpler version with less steps and resources?

Comment: Depends on the resolution and type of output of what you require. Do you just need location or do you need area? And not sure where the points are coming from, you mean you would make a centroid of each pixel of the TIFFs? How does a bioregion relate to a species - I think you have been loose with the terminology which makes it a bit hard to understand.

Comment: The input tiff file is a raster file based on one value per pixel, all with the same size. pixel size = 25 m, Dimensions: x=13932, Y=8824. The output is the summary of the values of all pixels per biogeregion. I do not need the area, just the summary statistics as a basis for post-processing maps. As I need first to assign each pixel to a certain biogeoregion, I was thinking aobut raster pixels to points.

Comment: Raster pixels to points (centroids) sounds like the way to go. That is a plugin for QGIS https://github.com/borysiasty/pointsamplingtool  Make sure your projection / EPSG are the same / similar.